# Sinatra : how to use helpers in Mustache views

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mustache, helper

I want to use my Sinatra helpers methods in Mustache views.

I do this:

```
# in app.rb:
...
helpers do
  def helloworld
    "helloworld!"
  end
end
get '/'
  mustache :home
end
...

# in views/home
class App < Sinatra::Base
  module Views
    class Home < Mustache
      def hello
        helloworld
      end
    end
  end
end

# in home.mustache
<p>{{hello}}</p>
```

It does not work, I have the error message :

«undefined local variable or method `helloworld' for App::Views::Home:0x000000023ebd48»

How can I use my method helper in Mustache view ?

Or, how can I use my method helper directly from home.mustache ? like this :

```
# in home.mustache
<p>{{helloworld}}</p>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something with a module:

```
# app_helpers.rb
module AppHelpers
  def helloworld
    "helloworld!"
  end
end

# app.rb
helpers AppHelpers

get '/'
  mustache :home
end

# views/home.rb
class App < Sinatra::Base
  module Views
    class Home < Mustache
      include AppHelpers

      def hello
        helloworld
     end
   end
 end
```